# How to avoid reinitializing a useState variable in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I am working on a music app in React Native. This page will be re-opened several times, but I do not want the trackList to reset to [] everything the page is re-rendered, but instead to retain its values. I have included a simplified version of my code:

```
let existsTrackListener = false;

export default function Host({ navigation }) {
  const [trackList, setTrackList] = useState([]);

  if (!existsTrackListener) {
    setTrackListener(roomID, (t) => {
      if (t != null) {
        const newArray = [...trackList, t.name];
        setTrackList(newArray);
      }
    });
    existsTrackListener = true;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={trackList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: please add you full code i am not seeying existsTrackListener variable initialization and all

Comment: I have updated the code with this line. I feel this is all the code that is necessary to convey my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the state to live while the app is running, you can can use [react context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context).

If you want to persist the state on storage so it's available on the next launch of your app, consider using database. There are many databases available, such as SQLite, Realm, Firebase (cloud option).

Comment: This is helpful. The first option is more what I'm looking for. While useContext may work for me, I originally wanted my variable to be completely self-contained in this Host function, not passed from a parent. Is this the correct way to go about this?